How to configure a single foreign key to be used by multiple columns in a single table in a postgresql hasura database?
I'm using python (version 3.9.6) and sqlalchemy (version 2.0.30) for configuring the tables in my postgresql database. After the tables are created, then I'm making POST requests to my hasura endpoint to configure the relationships.
In the (reduced) code snippet below, I'm attempting to configure six relationships, of which only half are successful (three are failing). Are you able to please help me identify why these relationships aren't working, and what changes I need to make?

❌ category1: product.categoryId1 -> product_category.productCategoryId
❌ category2: product.categoryId2 -> product_category.productCategoryId
❌ category3: product.categoryId3 -> product_category.productCategoryId
✅ products1: product_category.productCategoryId -> [product.categoryId1]
✅ products2: product_category.productCategoryId -> [product.categoryId2]
✅ products3: product_category.productCategoryId -> [product.categoryId3]

My database consists of a ~20 tables, and the code below is working very well for dozens of relationships, but I'm receiving some errors for three relationships:
- product - {'error': 'Inconsistent object: in table "product": in relationship "category1": no foreign constraint exists on the given column(s)', 'path': '$.args', 'code': 'invalid-configuration', 'internal': [{'definition': {'comment': None, 'name': 'category1', 'source': 'default', 'table': {'name': 'product', 'schema': 'public'}, 'using': {'foreign_key_constraint_on': 'productCategoryId'}}, 'name': 'object_relation category1 in table product in source default', 'reason': 'Inconsistent object: in table "product": in relationship "category1": no foreign constraint exists on the given column(s)', 'type': 'object_relation'}]}
- product - {'error': 'Inconsistent object: in table "product": in relationship "category2": no foreign constraint exists on the given column(s)', 'path': '$.args', 'code': 'invalid-configuration', 'internal': [{'definition': {'comment': None, 'name': 'category2', 'source': 'default', 'table': {'name': 'product', 'schema': 'public'}, 'using': {'foreign_key_constraint_on': 'productCategoryId'}}, 'name': 'object_relation category2 in table product in source default', 'reason': 'Inconsistent object: in table "product": in relationship "category2": no foreign constraint exists on the given column(s)', 'type': 'object_relation'}]}
- product - {'error': 'Inconsistent object: in table "product": in relationship "category3": no foreign constraint exists on the given column(s)', 'path': '$.args', 'code': 'invalid-configuration', 'internal': [{'definition': {'comment': None, 'name': 'category3', 'source': 'default', 'table': {'name': 'product', 'schema': 'public'}, 'using': {'foreign_key_constraint_on': 'productCategoryId'}}, 'name': 'object_relation category3 in table product in source default', 'reason': 'Inconsistent object: in table "product": in relationship "category3": no foreign constraint exists on the given column(s)', 'type': 'object_relation'}]}

Here's the python sqlalchemy code for creating the tables:
from sqlalchemy import String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, mapped_column
import requests

class product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'
    productId = mapped_column(String, primary_key=True)
    title = mapped_column(String)
    description = mapped_column(String)
    categoryId1 = mapped_column(String, ForeignKey('product_category.productCategoryId'))
    categoryId2 = mapped_column(String, ForeignKey('product_category.productCategoryId'))
    categoryId3 = mapped_column(String, ForeignKey('product_category.productCategoryId'))
    # RELATIONSHIPS
    category1 = relationship('product_category', foreign_keys=[categoryId1], back_populates="products1")  # each product has a category1
    category2 = relationship('product_category', foreign_keys=[categoryId2], back_populates="products2")  # each product has a category2
    category3 = relationship('product_category', foreign_keys=[categoryId3], back_populates="products3")  # each product has a category3

class product_category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product_category'
    productCategoryId = mapped_column(String, primary_key=True)
    title = mapped_column(String)
    description = mapped_column(String)
    # RELATIONSHIPS
    products1 = relationship('product', foreign_keys=[product.categoryId1], back_populates='category1') # each category is category1 for multiple products
    products2 = relationship('product', foreign_keys=[product.categoryId2], back_populates='category2') # each category is category2 for multiple products
    products3 = relationship('product', foreign_keys=[product.categoryId3], back_populates='category3') # each category is category3 for multiple products

And here's the python code for my graphql relationships creations:
# Foreign Keys
def track_foreign_key_relationships(table_name, relationship_name, relationship_type, ref_table_name, ref_column_name, db_name):

    def create_object_relationship(source, table_name, relationship_name, ref_column):
        data = {
            "type": "pg_create_object_relationship",
            "args": {
                "table": table_name,
                "name": relationship_name,
                "source": source,
                "using": {
                    "foreign_key_constraint_on": ref_column
                }
            }
        }
        response = requests.post(HASURA_URL, json=data, headers=HASURA_HEADERS)
        return response.json()

    def create_array_relationship(source, table_name, relationship_name, ref_table, ref_column):
        data = {
            "type": "pg_create_array_relationship",
            "args": {
                "table": table_name,
                "name": relationship_name,
                "source": source,
                "using": {
                    "foreign_key_constraint_on": {
                        "table": ref_table,
                        "column": ref_column
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        response = requests.post(HASURA_URL, json=data, headers=HASURA_HEADERS)
        return response.json()
    
    if relationship_type == "array":
        return create_array_relationship(db_name, table_name, relationship_name, ref_table_name, ref_column_name)
    elif relationship_type == "object":
        return create_object_relationship(db_name, table_name, relationship_name, ref_column_name)
    else:
        return "Invalid relationship type"

def track_many_foreign_key_relationships(relationships):
    responses = []
    print('\nForeign Keys:')

    def track_foreign_key_relationship_wrapper(relationship):
        try:
            response = track_foreign_key_relationships(
                relationship['table_name'], 
                relationship['relationship_name'], 
                relationship['relationship_type'], 
                relationship['ref_table_name'],  
                relationship['ref_column_name'],
                'default'
            )
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            return {'error': str(e)}
    
    for relationship in relationships:
        try:
            response = track_foreign_key_relationship_wrapper(relationship)
            responses.append(response)
            print(f'- {relationship["table_name"]} - {response}')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Exception tracking relationship for table {relationship["table_name"]}: {e}')

    return responses


track_foreign_keys_response = track_many_foreign_key_relationships([
    {
    # ❌ FAILED!
    # each product has a category1
    "table_name": 'product',
    "relationship_name": "category1",
    "relationship_type": "object",
    "ref_table_name": 'product_category',
    "ref_column_name": "productCategoryId"
    },
    {
    # ❌ FAILED!
    # each product has a category2
    "table_name": 'product',
    "relationship_name": "category2",
    "relationship_type": "object",
    "ref_table_name": 'product_category',
    "ref_column_name": "productCategoryId"
    },
    {
    # ❌ FAILED!
    # each product has a category3
    "table_name": 'product',
    "relationship_name": "category3",
    "relationship_type": "object",
    "ref_table_name": 'product_category',
    "ref_column_name": "productCategoryId"
    },
    {
    # ✅ SUCCESSFUL!
    # each product category has multiple products as category1
    "table_name": 'product_category',
    "relationship_name": "products1",
    "relationship_type": "array",
    "ref_table_name": 'product',
    "ref_column_name": "categoryId1"
    },
    {
    # ✅ SUCCESSFUL!
    # each product category has multiple products as category2
    "table_name": 'product_category',
    "relationship_name": "products2",
    "relationship_type": "array",
    "ref_table_name": 'product',
    "ref_column_name": "categoryId2"
    },
    {
    # ✅ SUCCESSFUL!
    # each product category has multiple products as category3
    "table_name": 'product_category',
    "relationship_name": "products3",
    "relationship_type": "array",
    "ref_table_name": 'product',
    "ref_column_name": "categoryId3"
    }
])

With Much Gratitude 
